# Fabric.js remove object from toDataURL

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there any inbuilt attribute that is similar to `excludeFromExport`?

I feel like it's the `toDatalessObject` function, but I'm unsure of how to use it.

Comment: @ℊααnd I'm trying to save it as an image without certain objects in it i.e. Line objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't any built-in method to exclude certain objects from `toDataURL` .

But, here is a workaround that you could use to achieve that functionality ...

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

let rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, top: 75, left: 120, fill: 'black' });
let circle = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 25, top: 75, left: 25, fill: 'red' });
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.add(circle);

function _toDataURL(...objsToRemove) {
   objsToRemove.forEach(e => {
      canvas.remove(e);
   });
   let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
   objsToRemove.forEach(e => {
      canvas.add(e);
   });
   return dataURL;
}

let dataURL = _toDataURL(rect);
console.log(dataURL);
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: it's unfortunate that they have `excludeFromExport` but not something that removes it when converting to image. Do you know what `toDatalessObject` does?

Comment: `toDatalessObject` returns an object *(not image)* representation of canvas.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks.

Comment: If I made the objects have 0 visibility, will it still take up space?

Comment: um.. what you mean by *will it still take up space*?

Comment: Like will it bloat the saved image file? (sorry not too familiar with saving canvases). If I have 100 objects, and make 99 of them 0 visibility, will it be the same size as another canvas with only 1 object?

Comment: If the canvas size is static then **yes**, it'll be the same size *(regardless how many objects there are)*. If the canvas size is dynamic then **no**

Comment: Think you can help with my latest Fabric question? :)